# Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded in C:\wamp\www\filepath\cake\libs\model\datasources\dbo\dbo_mysql.php

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, execution-time

I am having tables with 2000 records (table1); I need to check the duplicates of records from table2 with 100 records on the basis of User Email address and User Phone number.

Application in cakephp 1.3

Table 1 and Table 2 have same structure-

```
id, First Name, Last Name, Email, Street, Area, Locality, Country, Postal Code, Phone Number, Hobbies.
```

I imported data in mysql database with php excel reader and data store properly with more than 2000 records in Table 1.
After then I check the duplicates. If Table 1 data is matched with Table 2 with columns "email and phone number", then duplicate entry and duplicate flag enabled in Table 1 and record should not store in Table 2; All the process goes fine but after 853 records application stop
I also tried with Maximum Execution Time - 120 seconds. then my application stops after matching 1453 records.

> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded in C:\wamp\www\filepath\cake\libs\model\datasources\dbo\dbo_mysql.php on line 213

I am facing this error. Any one knows the best way to resolve this issue?

Comment: Seems a lot of time to check for duplicates. What are you asking to do exactly? Do you want to optimize code and reduce time of execution, or just want to know how to allow more time for execution?

Comment: Please show your table schemas, code, and the resulting query/queries, and please always mention your exact CakePHP version!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have your SQL  tables properly indexed by the columns you're checking against? I'm sorry but even with a low powered server 2000 records should be well less than one second ... if you have indexes setup. (I have a small desktop server with 4GB or RAM that checks name, email phone number from 5500 contacts in 300ms, for example)

Post you database creation schema, let's take a look

Answer (score -1):

You should increase max_execution_time more than 120 in php.ini. That helps me when I got this kind of error.

Hope it helps!

Comment: It would be way better to fix the actual problem

Comment: There is no better way for the problem he mentioned

Comment: How about trying to optimize the query?

Comment: It might work but I don't think his query is the problem right now.

Comment: @MiheretabAlemu Excuse me? Nobody knows what exactly the OP is doing, but comparing two tables, one with 2000, the other with 100 records, should be done in fractions of a second, even without indices!